# OneDrive - Two accounts, two folders

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I've two OneDrive accounts - one personal and one for business.
Is there a way to manage and sync both at the same time under Windows 10, e.g., sync one to c:\OneDrivePersonal and the other one to c:\OneDriveBusiness

Or do I always have to switch the account in the OneDrive settings manually (multiple times a day) ?